# Calculus problem on limits giving weird answers!

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I got this problem as homework and I just don't seem to solve this problem:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2}\frac{\cot x}{2x - \pi} $$

The answer to the problem as said by the book is $\frac{1}{2}$.

I end up getting weird answers for it (I think the question itself is wrong But needed a second opinion!)

Comment: Any edits or hints will be helpful

Comment: L'Hopital's rule should work here.

Comment: Do you have available the derivative of $\cot$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\cot(x)$ as $\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$. We then have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \dfrac{\cot(x)}{2x-\pi}& = \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \dfrac1{\sin(x)} \cdot\dfrac{\cos(x)}{2x-\pi} = \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \dfrac1{\sin(x)} \cdot \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \dfrac{\cos(x)}{2x-\pi}\\
& = 1 \cdot \lim_{\pi/2-t \to \pi/2} \dfrac{\cos(\pi/2-t)}{2\left(\pi/2-t\right)-\pi} = \lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(t)}{-2t}\\
& = -\dfrac12 \lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(t)}t\\
& = - \dfrac12
\end{align}

Comment: You think the answer givent by the book itself is wrong!

Comment: I'm OK with That

Comment: @pradyumnarahul Yes, the right answer is $-1/2$